# Stop heap allocation via make_shared

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to force my object to be on the stack to enforce very strict semantics and address some lifetime concerns.  I've read a couple articles on how to do this, and arrived at making `operator new` private (or deleted).  This seems to work as expected when `new` is used directly, but `make_shared` compiles fine.

```
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>

class A
{
private:
   void *operator new( size_t );
   void operator delete( void* );
   void *operator new[]( size_t );
   void operator delete[]( void* );
};

int main()
{
//  A* a = new A;      // Correctly produces compile error
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a2 = boost::make_shared<A>();
}
```

Using `new A` directly gives me this error as expected:

```
error: ‘static void* A::operator new(size_t)’ is private
```

I am guessing that `make_shared` is working because it is using the placement new operator, but I couldn't find any articles that discussed how to prohibit this.  The best solution I've come up with is to explicitly delete a template specialization for `make_shared`

```
namespace boost
{
    template<>
    shared_ptr<A> make_shared<A>() = delete;
};
```

This is obviously very specific to `boost::make_shared` though.  Is this really the best way?

Comment: Missing some `static` modifiers from your code?

Comment: Item 27 of More Effective C++ advises that if what you want to achieve is at all possible, it's quite hard. Sutter's maxim of protecting against Machiavelli also comes to mind: any user that can incorrectly use your type with dynamic allocation can incorrectly use it otherwise, by design of the language. Lifetime concerns are addressed via restricting construction only -- where the object resides will not and should not have a bearing.

Comment: @Luc I'm only trying to make users think twice when putting it on the heap and not using it as a stack variable.  The semantics are still correct on the heap, its just a little easier to misuse in that case.

Comment: To give you perspective, More Effective C++ was published in 1996. What you want to achieve is certainly reasonable, and desirable. If there was a convenient way to do it, we'd all be using it. As it turns out the language isn't set up that way, and we haven't found a worthwhile way.

Comment: @Luc Thanks.  I've restricted some of the construction, but then started going down this rathole.  I'll look at the problem from the construction angle to see how I can refit the problem from that angle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placement forms of `new` are pretty easy to handle -- they just come with extra arguments.  For example, the simple placement form is

```
void* operator new(std::size_t, void*);
```

Note that 18.6.1.3 prohibits redefining these at global scope; however there should be no problem with redefining (or deleting/making inaccessible) them for your particular type.

Unfortunately, `make_shared` uses scoped `::new  (pv)  T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`.  And as I mentioned, you aren't allowed to mess with the global placement new.  So you can't prevent it at compile-time, and any runtime trap would be a hack (checking the `this` pointer to see whether it's in-bounds of the stack).

Comment: It still compiles fine after adding this to `A`.

Comment: @JaredC: Hmm, let me look up the Standard verbiage on `make_shared`.  Is it `boost::make_shared` or `std::make_shared` you're using?  I see a `boost` header.

Comment: `boost::make_shared`.  No difference with `std::make_shared`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot enforce that objects of a class are always on the stack by making any operators inaccessible only: Any object which can be constructed on the stack can also be embedded as a member into another object. Even though your original class might struggle against being allocated on the heap the containing class won't. I'd think this is what happens in the case of `boost::make_shared()`: Internally it probably allocates some record containing both its administration data plus the object actually being allocated. Alternatively, it may use allocation function from some sort of allocator which don't map to the type's `operator new()` but use its own `operator new()` overload instead.

I'm not sure if it is possible to prevent heap allocations (at least, when the object is embedded into another object) but any approach doing so would need to make the constructors inaccessible (most likely `private`) and use some sort of factory functions, possibly in combination with moving. On the other hand, if you can move an object you have an accessible constructor and nothing prevents the object from being moved into an object on the heap.

If you specifically want to prevent the use of `std::make_shared()` for a concrete type (or `boost::make_shared()` although I can't quote the rules for specializing the latter), you can specialize `std::make_shared()`: According to 17.6.4.2.1 [namespace.std] paragraph 1 a user is allowed to specialize any template (unless otherwise specified) if it involves a user-defined type. Thus, you can prevent `A` from being used with `std::make_shared()`:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    A(int);
};

namespace std
{
    template <> std::shared_ptr<A> make_shared<A>() = delete;
    template <> std::shared_ptr<A> make_shared<A, int>(int&&) = delete;
}
namespace boost
{
    template <> boost::shared_ptr<A> make_shared<A>() = delete;
    template <> boost::shared_ptr<A> make_shared<A, int>(int&&) = delete;
}
```

Obviously, if you have multiple constructors in `A` you might need to add more specializations. ... and if your type happens to be a class template or your constructor to be a template, you'll be out of luck: You cannot partially specialize function templates.

With respect to your question about placement `new` (which may or may not be used by `make_shared()`): The placement `new` (and `delete`) signatures are these:

```
void* operator new(size_t, void*) noexcept;
void* operator new[](size_t, void*) noexcept;
void  operator delete(void*, void*) noexcept;
void  operator delete[](void*, void*) noexcept;
```

(see 18.6 [support.dynamic] paragraph 1). I doubt that making them inaccessible will help you anything, though.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really just trying to enforce this in the common case so someone can't accidentally do it.  If they want to circumvent it, then so be it, but at least it will be obvious in their code that they're doing something non-standard.  Unfortunatly, `make_shared` is a very common case for me which is why I'm trying to prevent it.

Comment: No, `make_shared` doesn't embed the object as a class member.  It uses scoped placement new.

Comment: @JaredC: If you specifically want to prevent `make_shared()` it becomes an entirely different question, though: Can standard function templates be specialized for user-defined types? ... and the answer is: You can explicitly specialize a template from the standard library if the specialization involves a user-defined type (17.6.4.2.1 [namespace.std] paragraph 1). Maybe you want `template <> shared_ptr<A> make_shared<A>() = delete;` (or something along these lines).